# Not able to close input stream

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, inputstream

in this application i am running a remote service where i am starting a separate thread to run TCP connection... on application exit, i have to close the input stream for which i am giving a thread interrupt and changing a boolean value (stopBroadcastRequested) .. when that is satisfied in the thread block i am closing the inputstream, but it does not get closed actually... if i manually give the instream.close within the thread during normal thread execution, the input stream closes as expected.. but in the if(stopBroadcastRequested){ block of code}, it does not work..can someone tell me what is the mistake i have made...

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

    class Task implements Runnable{
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!stopBroadcastRequested){
            Log.i(TAG, "Thread Task started");          
            try {
                isSocketOpen = broadCastComm.isAliveOrOpenSocket("192.168.43.2", 6000, 17, 0);

                if(isSocketOpen){
                    Log.d("SERVICE CLASS", "STARTED THREAD - Writing in output stream");

                    notificationMngr.cancelAll();
                    isShowingNotification = false;
                    outStream = broadCastComm.getCurrentOutputStream();
                    outStream.write(messageToBeSent);
                    if(Integer.valueOf(messageToBeSent[2]) != (byte)0xA0){
                        Log.e("REVERTING", "REVERTING");
                        messageToBeSent = mFormatter.formBroadCastMessage("GET_PERIPH_DATA");
                    }

                    Log.d("OUTPUT STREAM", "Message sent ->" + ByteArrayToString(messageToBeSent));
                }else{
                    connectivityStatusHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }

                Thread.sleep(3000L);

                if(isSocketOpen){

                }

            } catch (Throwable t) { 
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve data in thread", t);
            }
            Log.d("SERVICE CLASS", "End of THREAD");

        }

        if(stopBroadcastRequested){
            Log.e("SERVICE", "STOPPED THREAD");
            try {
                Log.e("*****THREAD", "CLOSED INPUT STARTED");
                if(inStream != null)
                    inStream.close();

                Log.e("*****THREAD", "CLOSED INPUT CLOSED");
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                Log.e("*****THREAD", "CLOSED OUTPUT");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("THREAD", "FAILED TO CLOSE STREAMS");
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopThread(){
        stopBroadcastRequested = true;
    }

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(TAG, "Service destroying");
    stopBroadcastRequested = true;
    serviceThread.interrupt();


    cleanNotifications();
    broadCastComm.clearConnections();
    //dbHandler.removeCallbacks(dbUpdater);
    try {
        dbHelper.cleanup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SERVICE", "Failed to clear DB connections");
    }
}
```

}

```
  ------LOG
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288): Failed to retrieve data in thread
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288): java.lang.InterruptedException
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288):     at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288):     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1213)
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288):     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1195)
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288):     at      com.RBEI.TTApp.BroadcastService$Task.run(BroadcastService.java:126)
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/BroadcastService(20288):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-30 19:28:03.878: DEBUG/SERVICE CLASS(20288): End of THREAD
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/SERVICE(20288): STOPPED THREAD
05-30 19:28:03.878: ERROR/*****THREAD(20288): CLOSED INPUT STARTED
05-30 19:28:03.882: ERROR/*****THREAD(20288): CLOSED INPUT CLOSED
05-30 19:28:03.882: ERROR/*****THREAD(20288): CLOSED OUTPUT
```

Comment: Log.e("SERVICE", "STOPPED THREAD"); Is this line actually executed?

Comment: yes.. it is executed....

Comment: when i give either within this while(buf.available() > 0){} or just outside of this during normal execution, it closes as expected,... but does not work in the interrupt block...is this some threading issue..like shared resource or something...

Comment: You call `inStream.close();` quite a few times.  Perhaps the first shot closes it and you're seeing failure to close on the subsequent closures.

Comment: hmmm... if it closes once then it should be fine..cause in the server  it would close...

Comment: i have removed the unwanted is.close() now...still it behaves the same way...

Comment: i have added the log now...above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the issue was that i was not unbinding the service properly which was causing all these issue... was not using the proper context for unbinding within the tabactivity.. had to use getApplicationContext() instead... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use close() only once. Just add a check `if (inStream != null { inStream.close(); )`
every time.

Comment: hmmm....when i put a breakpoint and check it works...i am not sure why it needs that delay for that to work...

Comment: well, if you don't find the solution, I suppose putting this code into AsyncTask would work fine. I think it should currently give you kind of InterruptedException due to thread sleep?

Comment: no, not at all. This is kind of a wrapper to use in order to perform background operation in a very effective and user-friendly way. There are plenty of tutorials like this: http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: I also suggest you to try removing Thread.sleep method and check out if issue can be replicated

Comment: hmmm.... why not use a handler? guess Async task needs to be started from the UI thread.. this whole code is running in a remote service..is it adviceable?

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception (InterruptedException) at line

```
Thread.sleep(3000L);
```

This happens before you even assign a value to the inStream variable,
so

```
inStream = broadCastComm.getCurrentInputStream();
```

is never executed. You can't close a Socket which is null.

Comment: i am not using this now...inStream = broadCastComm.getCurrentInputStream();